# Doxygen issue with output format

Tags: c, doxygen

I am seeing a lot of pages with std:: stuff:: more stuff when I run my doxygen on my c code.

How do I get rid of this in the config file? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are **[namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/)** which is a feature of C++.
Your code must be having some C++ source files perhaps. 
They indicate which namespace/scope a class resides in.
Ideally, You should not get rid of those. They are a part of documentation.

> # If the HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES tag is set to NO (the default) then Doxygen
>    # will show members with their full class and namespace scopes in the
>    # documentation. If set to YES the scope will be hidden.
>
> HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO

Comment: Which item in the config file do I change for that?